Keeping a user Authenticated while app is not actively visible
I am making an app that will send realtime location data to a database. Whenever I send the data while the app is open, everything works well, but if the app is not actively on the screen the user loses authentication and I can't update the row because my RLS only allows Authenticated users to update their own row. How can I keep the user Authenticated when the app is not actively visible?
I have tried using both a background and foreground service( don't know if I did it right). If I disable Row Level Security it works because the auth id is not needed.

I'm not sure this has anything to do with PostgreSQL. You probably need to provide some details on exactly how you are authenticating with your app.
